# Is there anything wrong with this approach to calling super() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I'm working on a project and decided that the best way to implement the functionality I wanted was to override a method. At the time I didn't realize that javascript had no notion of just calling super() so I started doing some research.

I found an article (http://blog.salsify.com/engineering/super-methods-in-javascript) that describes several methods of calling super methods.

I wan't super happy about any ofthose options though and came up with the following. Also available on fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/fpgm8j9n/.

```
var Food = function( name ){
    this.name = name;
}

Food.prototype.sayName = function(){
    console.log( 'I am a ' + this.name );
}

var Fruit = function( name, color ){
    Food.call( this, name );
    this.color = color;

    this.super = Object.getPrototypeOf( Object.getPrototypeOf( this ) );
}

Fruit.prototype = Object.create( Food.prototype );

Fruit.prototype.sayName = function(){
    console.log( 'I am a fruit and I am the color ' + this.color );
}

var orange = new Fruit( 'apple', 'red' );

// runs the overridden method in orange
orange.sayName(); // I am a fruit and I am the color red

// runs the super method
orange.super.sayName.call( orange ); // I am a apple
```

The following is the first example in article I posted. Are these essentially the same just without having to know your parent prototype? Is there any thing wrong with the implementation that I came up with or anything that can be improved? I'm pretty new to OOP in javascript and feel kind of wobbly with a lot of the concepts.

```
var Child = Parent.extend({
  // ...
  doSomething: function(x, y) {
    this.doSomethingElse(x);
    return Parent.prototype.doSomething.call(this, x, y);
  }
});
```

Comment: this is just few words from me. javascript is not really polymorphic language. don't force yourself to use it like other polymorphic languages.

Comment: I would recommend reading [**You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes**](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes) ([specifically chapter 4](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch4.md)) to understand what JavaScript can offer you in terms of inheritance.

Comment: I made a javascript class system, available from https://github.com/JakarCo/JDOM that you could try. I have a couple example usages in my question on codereview at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87983/javascript-class-system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common use case for `super` is for an overriding method to call the method it overrode (thereby using the existing functionality and further extending it with more code).  So in your example:

```
Fruit.prototype.sayName = function(){
    this.super.sayName.call(this);                 // prints "I am a apple"
    console.log( 'I am the color ' + this.color ); // prints "I am the color red"
}

var orange = new Fruit( 'apple', 'red' );
orange.sayName();
```

Calling the superclass method of an object from outside its methods (as in `orange.super.sayName.call( orange );` is an arguably non-OO practice.  The user of your object should not need to know what its type or supertype are.  They should just be able to ask it to do something (like print information about itself) and the object should figure out how to do that on its own.

The `super` field you created works well for this purpose, in that it allows overriding methods to call the methods they override.  However, it will break down if your inheritance hierarchy is deeper than one level:

```
var Grape = function(variety) {
    Fruit.call(this, "grape", "purple");
    this.variety = variety;
};

Grape.prototype = Object.create(Fruit.prototype);

Grape.prototype.sayName = function() {
    this.super.sayName.call(this);
    console.log('I am a ' + this.variety + ' grape');
};

var concordGrape = new Grape("Concord");
concordGrape.sayName(); // unbounded recursion / causes stack overflow
```

The reason is that the `this.super` field remains the same regardless of which level of the hierarchy uses it:

```
this                                               // Grape object
Object.getPrototypeOf(this)                        // Grape.prototype
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)) // Fruit.prototype
```

So when `Grape.prototype.sayName` calls `this.super.sayName`, it's calling `Fruit.prototype.sayName`, as intended.  But when `Fruit.prototype.sayName` calls `this.super.sayName`, it is unfortunately calling itself.

This cannot be fixed by redefining `super` at each level:

```
var Grape = function(variety) {
    Fruit.call(this, "grape", "purple");
    this.variety = variety;
    this.super = Object.getPrototypeOf( Object.getPrototypeOf( this ) );
};
```

`this` points to the same object regardless of which function in the hierarchy is referring to it.

What is really needed is for `super` to know the hierarchy level of the function that is using it (so it could invoke the corresponding function from the level above).  I'm not aware of any foolproof way to do this, other than those in the article you linked.

Comment: `The user of your object should not need to know what its type or supertype are. They should just be able to ask it to do something (like print information about itself) and the object should figure out how to do that on its own.` yes.